# Unable to remove splitter outline

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a panel with west and center regions. When I click on a splitter, it gets some nasty outline that looks like so:

[image]

You can see this blue outline, that now makes it impossible to see the arrow. I investigated the DOM and found classes `x-splitter-vertical`, `x-splitter-focus` and `x-splitter-default-focus`. I tried to remove the outline like so:

```
.x-splitter-focus, .x-splitter-default-focus, .x-splitter-vertical { 
    outline: none !important;
    border: 0px !important;
}
```

But it does not help. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please share a demo of your problem. JSFiddle or a live demo so that the problem can be seen

Comment: Looks like you have some kind of layout issue. JSFiddle will help us to provide more information

Comment: I will make a fiddle in a minute.

Comment: Here is a fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1us6 . To see the nasty outline just click two times on the splitter arrow.

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine to me on chrome. Is your issue browser specific?

Comment: I'm working in FF now. I will check it in Chrome in a second.

Comment: Well, on Chrome I also see this blue outline, which I want to remove completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried is the standard-compliant way of doing things. ExtJS does not use the standard-compliant way of doing things, because they have to support browsers which are not standards compliant; e.g. no "outline".

The blue box can be removed with the following CSS:

```
.x-splitter-focus:after {
    border-width:0;
}
```